# How to move directory /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, archlinux

Archlinux, MariaDB 10.1.25

I have working mysql. Now I decided to move directory with data.

I tried to move /var/lib/mysql to /home/srv/mysql. And creat symlink to old path (/var/lib/mysql). But mysqld gives error:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status mariadb.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

systemctl  status mariadb.service:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-08-02 20:19:17 +10; 7min ago
  Process: 29629 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 29576 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exite
  Process: 29575 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 29629 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"
```

Access rights are correct. User mysql, group mysql.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check your my.cnf file, there might be following option set:

```
symbolic-links = 0
```

I'm not sure though, if this fixes the problem.

I recommend fixing the issue in another way. Instead of using symbolic links, simply adjust the data dir in your my.cnf with

```
datadir = /home/srv/mysql
```